# reading a port (GPIO) value in C (beagleboard-xm)

Tags: c, beagleboard, gpio

I have an embedded board (beagleboard-xm) that runs ubuntu 12.04. I need to read a GPIO continuously to see if the value of the port changes. My code is herebelow:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

FILE *fp;

int main(void)
{
    //linux equivalent code "echo 139 > export" to export the port
    if ((fp = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/export", "w")) == NULL){
            printf("Cannot open export file.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        fprintf( fp, "%d", 139 );
        fclose(fp);
      //  linux equivalent code "echo low > direction" to set the port as an input 
        if ((fp = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio139/direction", "rb+")) == NULL){
            printf("Cannot open direction file.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        fprintf(fp, "low");
        fclose(fp);

       // **here comes where I have the problem, reading the value**
        int value2;
        while(1){
        value2= system("cat /sys/class/gpio/gpio139/value");
        printf("value is: %d\n", value2);
        }
    return 0;
}
```

the code above reads the port continuously (`0` by default), however, when I change the port as `1`, `system` call output the correct value, however `printf` still prints `0` as an output. What is the problem with `value2` that does not store the value that `system()` outputs.

If I use the code below instead of `while` loop above, I get an error about opening the `value` file (Cannot open value file.), if I put the `fopen` line outside of `while` loop, it does not show the changes in the `value` file.

```
char buffer[10];
while(1){
    if ((fp = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/gpio139/value", "rb")) == NULL){
            printf("Cannot open value file.\n");
            exit(1);
        }
    fread(buffer, sizeof(char), sizeof(buffer)-1, fp);
    int value = atoi(buffer);
    printf("value: %d\n", value);

    }
```

My question: how do I need to fix the code? or how should I read the `value` file?
As an additional info that I wonder: what is the difference to e.g. export the port by `system("echo 139 > /sys/class/gpio/export")` and `fp = fopen("/sys/class/gpio/export","w"); fprintf(fp,"%d",139);` which method do you suggest me to use? Why?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Calling `system(3)` is very expensive - your process first does a `fork(2)` and then `/bin/sh` is executed over the child to handle the command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `system()` function returns the return value of `cat`, which is 0. It does not return the standard output from `cat`, which is what you were expecting.

I think the problem with your second bit of code is that you're not calling `fclose()`. Since you're running in a tight loop, you almost immediately exceed the number of open files allowed.

So, call `fclose()`, and think about putting a `sleep()` in there too.

Answer (score 1):

When reading a file in C, your position in the file changes as you read it. For example, if you were to open a file with the contents:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
```

and run this program:

```
char buffer[1024];
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), theFile))
{
    printf("Buffer: %s", buffer);
}
```

It would print:

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
```

As you read each line, the position in the file changes to the next line.

In your program, after reading the value the first time, you are trying to read the empty space in the file, instead of the value you want.

The solution to your problem is to move `fopen` outside of the while loop, but call `fseek` to reset your position to the start of the file each time through the loop.

To use `fseek`, you need to pass it a file pointer, byte offset and seek point. Here you call it on your file, with a 0 byte offset from the waypoint SEEK_SET, which indicates the start of the file.

```
fseek(theFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Are you sure that seeking to the beginning of a pseudofile like those in `/sys` refreshes the content that the kernel will deliver?

Comment: Not sure, depends on how it was implemented. You'd just have to try it.